# PhoneGap Accessing FileSystem in Windows 8 App

Tags: cordova, windows-8

I've been working on a PhoneGap app for IOS and Android. I'm now migrating it to Windows 8 and having problems creating and accessing a directory with the following error: `Error getting Download/MyNewDirectory directory: ,File Quota Exceeded Error`.

The file system is retrieved without issue and running `FileSystem.root.fullPath` gives me: `"C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Packages\84d4fe3a-8719-4d22-9bfd-a0ae9d5c624d_0rbfcm4j9s1vw\LocalState"`. I tried manually adding 'Download/MyNewDirectory' to that `\LocalState` directory but still get the same error when trying to access them in the code with, `fileSystem.root.getDirectory("Download/MyNewDirectory", {
                    create: true,
                    exclusive: false
                }, function (directory) {...`

Does PhoneGap's File API work with Windows 8? I would rather not have to rewrite or shim the file access parts of the app.

EDIT:
Windows 8 is not listed as a supported platform for File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out article series "Windows 8 apps for the PhoneGap developer". 
This particular article covers file access.

http://css.dzone.com/articles/windows-8-apps-phonegap-0

Answer (score 2):

If you double-click the App-Manifest file in the projects main folder in solutions explorer, you will see a capabilities tab.  you need to tick Documents, next to that tab there is another tab (forget name) to set extensions - you need to configure the file extensions and standard mime types. i believe this may be the source of your issue if you havent tried this.. Ms docs say it is needed to allow your app to read and write files to the documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else like me that was struggling with this, add the capabilities that weeasle mentions, then try using:

```
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Windows.Foundation.Uri(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + 'www/assets/pages/navigation.html')).done(gotControls, fail);
```

Using that code was the only way I could get it to work with html files as it would fail every time when using the following (that worked on iOS and Android):

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.applicationDirectory + "www/assets/pages/en/navigation.html", gotControls, fail);
```

Hope that helps.